# Please identify this SMD part SOT23-6 with top marking 010

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Please identify this SMD part **SOT23-6** with top marking **010** and bottom marking **1318** as shown in attached photo. I have tried my best in search but without success, appreciate if you tell me how you were able to find it.

[image: SOT23-6 Top Marking 010]

Comment: Muthanna A. Alwahash - Hi, (a) I changed your request from "can someone help me..." since that is just a yes/no answer. However it's obvious that you want to identify the component, so I've changed the question to say that. (b) Identification questions here are usually about components on PCBs etc. where we can get context about the component from the surrounding circuit. That isn't possible when you only show the component :( Do you have *any* other information about this component or its function? If so, please [edit] the question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the part?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any other context that I can add, components are new not from a PCB I got it in one of my 5 years old orders along with many other components and now I can't identify it.

Answer (score 2):

Not confirmed but it could be [FDG6301N](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdg6301n-d.pdf). Based on the linked datasheet, the marking scheme is `01M` where `M` is some date code:

[image: Marking code and pinout from datasheet]

<sup>Screenshot from [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdg6301n-d.pdf)</sup>

Comment: Could you [edit] and expand upon your reasoning?

Comment: No it is not, marking on FDG6301N is .21 as mentioned in its datasheet

Comment: Then please delete your answer, if you feel that it isn't correct.

Comment: Well the datasheet is a bit confusing about markings. https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdg6301n-d.pdf "01M" ( 01 = Specific Device Code
M = Assembly Operation Month) and on page 6 "XXXM" (XXX = Specific Device Code
M = Date Code*)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no e3 logo and no datecode in the bottom https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20200716_onsemi-FDG6301N_C236893_front.jpg

Comment: FDG6301N package type is SC-88 and what I have is SOT23-6. I don't think this answer is correct.